# MySQL. Значение в поле в записях поделить на максимальное значение этого поля

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как быть. Есть таблица, она у меня формируется после выборки, выглядит так:

Код выборки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно же получить вот такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. значение sumrunk делится на максимальное значение этого поля и сохраняется в поле rel

Пробовал так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка Error Code: 1146. Table 'search_engine.t1' doesn't exist

Ну тут понятно, таблица t1 еще не создалась, а я уже максимум по полю ищу.

пробовал еще так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате выходит только первая запись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел пока только такое решение. Выборка сохраняется как таблица t1, находим в ней максимум по полю sumrunk. И потом еще раз делаю выборку создается таблица t2 и пробегаю по каждой записи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По тз создавать новые таблицы не рекомендовано, поэтому делаю через AS.
Так то все работает. Но есть ли какое нибудь решение короче и компактнее?

Comment: Версия MySQL - какая?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql/1035#1035) [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: версия  MySQL 8.0.27

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO

Исходные данные:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (page_id INT, `rank` INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,3),(3,2);
```

Запрос:

```sql
SELECT page_id, 
       SUM(`rank`) / MAX(SUM(`rank`)) OVER () rel
FROM test
-- WHERE ...
GROUP BY page_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02b1486c52979ac3f0cea02c5ba1194d)

Comment: Офигеть! Спасибо! Я знал, что тут боги Mysql сидят :D